# columns inside columns don´t fill the width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, styling

I've searched for a solution but can't find any..

I'm using Bootstrap and I have columns inside columns, but it seams like I'm missing something. See the example on jsfiddle to get more info:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3172/)

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="yellow col-xs-4">

    </div>
    <div class="green col-xs-4">

    </div>

    <div class="orange col-xs-4">

    </div>
```

How do I get the `.problem` columns to fit like these over... (take full width)

```
    <div class="height grey col-xs-8">        
        <div class="yellow col-xs-4 problem">problem</div>
        <div class="green col-xs-4 problem">problem</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="height grey col-xs-4">
        <div class="orange col-xs-4 problem">problem</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest columns inside of other columns within a `div.row`.  Also, when nesting columns, you still are working with a fluid grid of 12 columns inside its parent.  Here is updated markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yellow col-xs-4">           
        </div>
        <div class="green col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="orange col-xs-4">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">      
        <div class="height grey col-xs-8"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="yellow col-xs-6 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
                <div class="green col-xs-6 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="height grey col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="orange col-xs-12 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what was done here is adding nested `rows` inside of each column that contains columns inside of it, and changing the `col-xs-#` column class values appropriately so that each parent container adds up to 12 columns.  It looks like you should spend a little more time familiarizing yourself with the fluid grid and how nesting grids inside the grid works.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3186/)

[**Official Bootstrap CSS documentation for nesting grid elements**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

**Edit: to update JSFiddle and add `.container` wrapper `div`**

Comment: How could I get rid of that extra padding on the "green col-xs-6 problem" column? I´m trying to have 3 equal columns.

Comment: What do you mean? They all have equal padding.  If you're talking about the borders, it's due to some CSS classes having borders and others not... just remove all that.

Comment: All 3 elements on the bottom and top are the same width, same padding (remove all `border` styles in your CSS and you see what I mean).  However `.row` elements have `margin` of `-15px` on left and right, which makes the middle one look bigger because the left and right ones' padding is off the screen.  I don't use Bootstrap generally but I assume this is due to the lack of an appropriate container element.

Comment: @Plexus81 [here is an updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3185/) that adds a `.container` div and takes care of the negative margin issue.  Updating my answer accordingly.  Does that answer your question? All columns are now equal width and padding.

Comment: @Plexus81 also if this does solve your problem please accept it as the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3172/

The columns, even nested, should sum to 12. It is a good idea to wrap nested columns in their own row div, though it might not be completely necessary.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="yellow col-xs-4">

    </div>
    <div class="green col-xs-4">

    </div>

    <div class="orange col-xs-4">

    </div>        
<br/>        
    how to I get the problem colums to fit like those over..
    <div class="height grey col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="yellow col-xs-6 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
          <div class="green col-xs-6 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="height grey col-xs-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="orange col-xs-12 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested columns should add up to 12 for full width.

```
<div class="height grey col-xs-12">        
    <div class="yellow col-xs-4 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
    <div class="green col-xs-4 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>
    <div class="orange col-xs-4 problem">problem, this column should have the same width as over</div>  
</div>
```